# What is the intention/idea behind having the assignment operation in JavaScript return the value assigned?

Tags: javascript, return-value, assignment-operator

```
var foo, bar;
if (foo = true) {
    console.log('I am so true!');
}

if (bar = false) {
    console.log('Why am I not being logged?');
}
```

Also on a JavaScript console, when I do

```
var test;
test = 'I will be printed'
```

the string will be printed/returned.

In JavaScript, the assignment operation returns the assigned value. Is this behavior according to ECMAScript standard or is it just the implementation? This behavior is different than other languages like `c`, is there any intention behind this? If yes, what?

Comment: @harsha the question was is "what does the assigment operator return." Not "what does the compare operator return."

Comment: @0xc0de Did you actually try console logging it yourself to see what was returned?

Comment: @Zenith: Yes, maybe I should edit the question to drop 'what' and keep just the 'why' portion which is exactly what I want to ask.

Comment: The problem with the "why" question is that only someone who designed JS can truly answer that question: Brendan Eich.

Answer (score 6):

> In JavaScript, what does an assignment operation return?

The value that was assigned, i.e. the right hand side of the expression.

> Is the above behavior according to ECMAScript standard or is it just the implementation?

It is defined in [§11.13.1 in the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.13.1):

> The production *`AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression`* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LeftHandSideExpression*.
>
> 2. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *AssignmentExpression*.
>
> 3. Let *rval* be `GetValue(rref)`.
>
> [...]
>
> 6. Return *rval*.

---

> Why is this behavior different than other languages like c, is there any intention behind this?

I don't know how it is in C, but if you are asking for reasons regarding certain design decisions, you should contact Brendan Eich, the creator of JavaScript.

FWIW, you can find the same behavior in other languages, like PHP and Python (these are the ones I'm certain about, I *think* Java is working the same way as well).

Comment: Dunno why the language is like that either, but this particular feature is often leveraged, e.g. `while (x = a[i++]) { /* do stuff with x */}`.

Comment: Solid answer, citing the spec is always nice :) @0xc0de For what it's worth, the C specification states that "An
assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment " under "§6.5.16 Assignment operators". So this behavior is consistent across C as well as Java, Python and PHP. [C-Spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Code to support Felix's answer:

```
if (foo = false) {
    console.log('I am so true!');//won't print
}
if (foo = 0) {
    console.log('I am so true!');//won't print
}
if (foo = undefined) {
    console.log('I am so true!');//won't print
}
```